# Find the number that gives the max number of steps for the Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I assume that $a$, $b$ are integers $a > b > 0$.

$N(a,b)$ denotes the number of steps taken in the Euclidean Algorithm to find $\gcd(a,b)$, for example, $N(7,2) = 2$. $M(a)$ then denotes the maximal $N(a,b)$, for example, $M(7) = 3$.

How can I then find the $b$ for any given a such that $N(a,b)$ is maximal?

Comment: Normally it is ive times the number of digits in the smaller integer. So between $a$ and $b$ which ever small, it is $5\times digits\{min\{a,b\}\}$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LamesTheorem.html and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Number_of_steps.

Comment: The slowest case for the Euclidean algorithm is when $a$ and $b$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers. E.g. $(34,21) \to (13,21) \to (13,8) \to (5,8) \to (5,3) \to (2,3) \to (2,1) \to (0,1)$. In this case, the number of steps required is about $\log_\varphi (a\sqrt 5) - 2$, where $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$ is the golden ratio. @Quintic's formula is an approximation to this, which would work if $\varphi^5$ were equal to $10$ (in fact $\varphi^5$ is close to $11$).